# Get file attributes (hidden, readonly, system, archive) in Python

Tags: python, attributes, operating-system, chmod, stat

Just started learning Python. How can i get a status of file's attributes in Python? I know that `os.chmod(fullname, stat.S_IWRITE)` delete readonly attribute, but how can i get status without changing it? I need to get all of the attributes of `"hidden"`, `"system"`, `"readonly"`, `"archive"`

Comment: which operating system, on linux for instance a hidden file is any file with a `.` as the first character of the name, on windows though I think it is a file attribute.

Answer (score 9):

You can use directly the Windows API like that

```
import win32con
import win32api
attrs = win32api.GetFileAttributes(filepath)
attrs & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM
attrs & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
```

Comment: What's the `attrs &` part do?

Comment: The FileAttributes is flags integer so you need to check each bit, each bit represent a boolean value.

Comment: Well after getting attr, how to extract those hidden or archived and other values from this?

Answer (score 5):

you need to take a look at module `stat` and `os.stat`

```
 os.stat(path)

Perform the equivalent of a stat() system call on the given path. (This function follows symlinks; to stat a symlink use lstat().)

The return value is an object whose attributes correspond to the members of the stat structure, namely:

    st_mode - protection bits,
    st_ino - inode number,
    st_dev - device,
    st_nlink - number of hard links,
    st_uid - user id of owner,
    st_gid - group id of owner,
    st_size - size of file, in bytes,
    st_atime - time of most recent access,
    st_mtime - time of most recent content modification,
    st_ctime - platform dependent; time of most recent metadata change on Unix, or the time of creation on Windows)
```

Comment: Where's the hidden attribute?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using python 3.4+ you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) [stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat) method.

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path(r"D:\temp\test.txt").stat())
```

Output:

```
os.stat_result(
    st_mode=33206, 
    st_ino=204632308068721491, 
    st_dev=67555953, 
    st_nlink=1, 
    st_uid=0, 
    st_gid=0, 
    st_size=4, 
    st_atime=1550757968, 
    st_mtime=1550757968, 
    st_ctime=1550757951
)
```

[here is more information about os.stat_result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result)

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.5, `os.stat()`, `os.fstat()` and `os.lstat()` returns a `class os.stat_result` that, on Windows systems, includes [`st_file_attributes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_file_attributes). You can use the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_* constants in the [`stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html) module to check the file attributes.

File attributes

```
>attrib test.txt
A    R               C:\test.txt
```

Sample code

```py
import os
import stat

fn   = "test.txt"
info = os.stat(fn)
print("Attributes of", fn)
if info.st_file_attributes & stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE:  print(" - archive")
if info.st_file_attributes & stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM:   print(" - system")
if info.st_file_attributes & stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN:   print(" - hidden")
if info.st_file_attributes & stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY: print(" - read only")
```

Output

```
Attributes of test.txt
 - archive
 - read only
```