# How do i determine if a file is read only

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, windows, macos

I'm writing a shell in python and need to determine if a file is read only for the current user. How do i interpret `os.stat(path)[0]` for a given user.
This isn't trivial on linux you may get write permissions because of user group or others. Then there's the concept of a user being in the files group with group write but is the owner with read only permissions.
I need this to be cross platform so it works on Mac Linux and Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file attributes (hidden, readonly, system, archive) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27196143/608639)

Comment: @jww, I've improved the question with an edit. it was rather poorly asked

Comment: For POSIX systems such as Linux and macOS, use `os.access(filename, os.W_OK)`. This should account for both file permissions and file attributes (e.g. immutability). In Windows, `os.access` only checks the readonly file attribute. The simplest way to check for write permission in Windows is to open the file via `CreateFileW` (via ctypes or PyWin32's win32file), requesting generic write access and sharing read, write, and delete access.

Comment: @ErykSun It's better to post it as an answer instead of just a comment. __________________ note that that will always return True for `root` user regardless of readonly flag on the file -- refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412234/296692

Answer (score 3):

```
statinfo = os.stat(path, *, dir_fd=None, follow_symlinks=True)
```

Here's a description from the documentation: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat

"Get the status of a file or a file descriptor. Perform the equivalent of a stat() system call on the given path. path may be specified as either a string or bytes – directly or indirectly through the PathLike interface – or as an open file descriptor. Return a stat_result object."